# How to calculate the forces acting on an object of mass 'm', which is vacuum gripped at the end of a robot arm?

Tags: robotic-arm

I would like to understand, how to calculate the forces/what all forces act on an object that is currently being gripped by a suction gripper and when it moves. Gravity is one, which will cause the object being gripped to fall, the angular velocity will try to move the object away from the eef, the suction force will try to retain the picked object. Is there a formula that ties all of these together and form a threshold, beyond which the gripped object will definitely fall.

Comment: What sort of environment are you considering? e.g. Underwater, in air, in space

Comment: On air, on earth. I want to calculate, a threshold force 'T', beyond which the object grasped by the vacuum gripper would fall, while the robot is in motion. I want to model that threshold force into robot's trajectory and calculate a threshold at way-points of the robot's motion.